# Sigma JS - "Error: The edge events feature is not compatible with the WebGL renderer"

Tags: sigma.js

I want to display a tooltip when hovering over an edge in Sigma JS graph. The tooltip should display the edge label.
In order to do that I added the following:

```
s.settings('enableEdgeHovering', true);
```

However, the tooltip is not displayed and I get the following error in the console:
"Error: The edge events feature is not compatible with the WebGL renderer". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Event on edge are not supported with the WebGL renderer.
You should use `canvas` instead.

Cheers.